# ASP.NET Core MVC base64 image to IFormFile

Tags: base64, asp.net-core-mvc, iformfile

I have a problem. I stored some images in DB as base64, and now I need to edit this object that contains this image. The image is uploaded by the user in a form and I converted it to `base64` and stored it in DB. Now my problem is how to convert `base64` string to IFormFile to display it for editing the whole object.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> If you're trying to get a object/viewModel that contains a Byte[]/base64,
>   i searched in hours for a solution but then i added extra parameter to my viewmodel

```
    public class ProductAddVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Categories Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Vat { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public Byte[] ByteImage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool? Available { get; set; }
}
```

The parameter Image is to store the new image that may be uploading in EDIT as you mentioned.
While the parameter ByteImage is to get the old image from Database.

> The where you're done editing you can convert the IFormFile to byte[] and save it in DataBase
>   I tried to use Mapper but it went wrong, this code is working 100% but i'm gonna make it look better

```
        internal ProductAddVM GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var model = new Product();
        model = Product.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        var viewModel = new ProductAddVM();
        viewModel.Id = model.Id;
        viewModel.Name = model.Name;
        viewModel.Available = model.Available;
        viewModel.Description = model.Description;
        viewModel.Price = model.Price;
        viewModel.Category = (Categories)model.Category;
        viewModel.Vat = model.Vat;
        viewModel.ByteImage = model.Image;
        return viewModel;
    }


    internal void EditProduct(int id, ProductAddVM viewModel,int userId)
    {
        var tempProduct = Product.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        tempProduct.Name = viewModel.Name;
        tempProduct.Available = viewModel.Available;
        tempProduct.Description = viewModel.Description;
        tempProduct.Price = viewModel.Price;
        tempProduct.Category =(int)viewModel.Category;
        tempProduct.Vat = CalculateVat(viewModel.Price,(int)viewModel.Category);
        if (viewModel.Image != null)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                viewModel.Image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                tempProduct.Image = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        tempProduct.UserId = userId;
        tempProduct.User = User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);

        SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Its works for me, in a big project with 3000+ users that uploaded  pictures